# Какой знак препинания нужно ставить после слова "разумеется"

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания нужно ставить после слова "разумеется" в данном предложении: "Разумеется это не страшно."

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ставить запятую. Вводные слова в русском языке выделяются запятыми.

Comment: Нужно заметить, что слово "разумеется" может также употребляться в качестве сказуемого. Но в данном предложении оно, как было сказано, является вводным словом и выделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном вами предложении нужно поставить запятую: "Разумеется**,** это не страшно".

Здесь "разумеется" — вводное слово,  которое требует обособления.

Cр.: Это, разумеется (= конечно, безусловно), не страшно.

Answer (score 1):

**РАЗУМЕЕТСЯ**

1. ***Вводное слово.***
   То же, что «конечно, несомненно, бесспорно». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми:
   *У каждого народа, разумеется, своя история.*
2. ***В значении сказуемого.***
   Как правило, слово «разумеется» в значении сказуемого встречается в конструкции «разумеется, что...».
3. ***Частица*** (в ответной реплике).
   То же, что «да». Обособляется или оформляется как отдельное предложение.
   [**Словарь-справочник по пунктуации**](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/617/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

В Вашем предложении "разумеется" является вводным словом и после него нужна запятая:
**"Разумеется, это не страшно".**

Вот похожие предложения:

*Разумеется, IRL не нравится договор Центристской партии с "Единой Россией"...*
(Прийт Сибул)
*Разумеется, противостояние с «Реалом» будет для меня особенным.*
(Хаби Алонсо)